# How long are you supposed to stay out of Israel after your 3 month tourist visa has expired in order to get another tourist visa?

Tags: visas, israel, tourist-visas

How long are you supposed to stay out of Israel after your 3 month tourist visa has expired in order to get another tourist visa?
I am Chilean citizen and I tried to get a meeting for extending my visa at the ministry but unfortunately they don't have any dates until October and my visa will end in September.

Comment: I can't find any information on this but it may be a good question to ask the ministry if you can remain in country while waiting for this appointment since it's that far off.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You ask how long to stay out of the country, but your main problem seems to be that you want to see the ministry but they don't have available spots?
So regardless, you're going to have to leave in September, surely? Unless as Karlson says, they let you stay while waiting, although from other countries that's unusual for tourist visas...